# country, state and city database structure for laravel 5.1 with mongo database

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.1

I'm using laravel 5.1 and mongo db. I need to create country, state and city in form. I checked that there is no normalization in mongo database so please guide me how to create database table structure for populating country, state and city. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well you can still "reference" one collection to another, you  should read more about [modeling in mongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/), basically the structure of your models will vary depending on which operation you perform more often and what's the use case for you.

For example, if you write a lot more than you are reading then having separated collections could be a good practice and if you read more than you write then having a structure with embedded objects may be fine for you.

for me I'd create a mix of both since you may have a lot of cities by state, so it would be good to have a separate collection. (but again that will depend on your use case)

this collection holds countries and states

```
{
    _id: ObjectId<>,
    countryName:"Spain",
    countryCode:"es",
    states[{
        _id: ObjectId<>,
        stateName:"Barcelona"
    }]
}
```

and then the other collection to fetch cities when is convenient.

```
{
 _id:ObjectId<>,
 _stateId:ObjectId<>, //Reference to you stateId
 cityName:"SomeCity or province"

}
```

that's a simple approach, that depends on your use case and how you are going to read your data but, in a simple scenario when you select a country and then a state and at last a city, that would work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply so you said that both normalized table and denormalized tables are possible in mongo db , right?. In this case how can I write join query to fetch cities or state in laravel 5.1. I checked that join queries are not in laravel 5.1. Can you please share me some examples query? It would be helpful for me. Thanks :)

Comment: there's no need to do "a join", you just need to do a query by stateId unfortunately, I'm not fluent in PHP (I don't like it); but I'm pretty sure you can google and find something.

Comment: Thanks for your help ripper :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add reference using the objectid created by the system. In mongodb there is no join queries. All you can do is application level joins if needed. Try to design your collections based on the data needs.